What can I do about sbf.mk Makefile include seeming to be incompatible with solana_sdk.h within the solana repository?
I am just getting started with Solana development. I am a C programmer so I am most comfortable with C. I am just using the most basic code to create a shared object file. I am on Ubuntu 22 x86-64. The clang version being used seems to be:
clang version 17.0.6 (https://github.com/anza-xyz/llvm-project.git 9003b439a0407ff1c1b06b52ffb4809bfb3ccff4)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/user/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/c/../dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin

My C file is:
#include "solana_sdk.h"

extern uint64_t entrypoint(const uint8_t *input)
{
    if (input == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

Here is my Makefile at the top of the repo:
OUT_DIR := ./build
INC_DIRS := /home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc
include ~/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/c/sbf.mk

Here, ~/dev/solana is the solana git repository.
make V=1 shows the following build command:
mkdir -p ./build/program/
/home/user/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/c/../dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/clang -Werror -O2 -fno-builtin -std=c17 -isystem/home/user/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/c/inc -isystem/home/user/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/c/../dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/lib/clang/17/include -I/home/user/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/c/../dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/include -I/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc  -target sbf -fPIC -o ./build/program/program.o -c ./src/program/program.c

It makes sense that c17 standard is being used since it is in the sbf.mk makefile include. However, I get the following build error:
In file included from ./src/program/program:1:
In file included from /home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/solana_sdk.h:6:
In file included from /home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/assert.h:6:
/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/types.h:39:34: error: '_Static_assert' with no message is a C2x extension [-Werror,-Wc2x-extensions]
   39 | static_assert(sizeof(int8_t) == 1);
      |                                  ^
      |                                  , ""
/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/types.h:40:35: error: '_Static_assert' with no message is a C2x extension [-Werror,-Wc2x-extensions]
   40 | static_assert(sizeof(uint8_t) == 1);
      |                                   ^
      |                                   , ""
/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/types.h:41:35: error: '_Static_assert' with no message is a C2x extension [-Werror,-Wc2x-extensions]
   41 | static_assert(sizeof(int16_t) == 2);
      |                                   ^
      |                                   , ""
/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/types.h:42:36: error: '_Static_assert' with no message is a C2x extension [-Werror,-Wc2x-extensions]
   42 | static_assert(sizeof(uint16_t) == 2);
      |                                    ^
      |                                    , ""
/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/types.h:43:35: error: '_Static_assert' with no message is a C2x extension [-Werror,-Wc2x-extensions]
   43 | static_assert(sizeof(int32_t) == 4);
      |                                   ^
      |                                   , ""
/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/types.h:44:36: error: '_Static_assert' with no message is a C2x extension [-Werror,-Wc2x-extensions]
   44 | static_assert(sizeof(uint32_t) == 4);
      |                                    ^
      |                                    , ""
/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/types.h:45:35: error: '_Static_assert' with no message is a C2x extension [-Werror,-Wc2x-extensions]
   45 | static_assert(sizeof(int64_t) == 8);
      |                                   ^
      |                                   , ""
/home/user/dev/solana/sdk/sbf/c/inc/sol/types.h:46:36: error: '_Static_assert' with no message is a C2x extension [-Werror,-Wc2x-extensions]
   46 | static_assert(sizeof(uint64_t) == 8);
      |                                    ^
      |                                    , ""
8 errors generated.
make: *** [/home/user/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/sdk/sbf/c/sbf.mk:263: build/program/program] Error 1

I am confused why the static asserts from the sdk in the solana repo would not be consistent with the C-standard mandated in the sbf.mk file. Am I doing something wrong? What is the solution? I would prefer not to edit the sbf.mk file or the solana sdk header files, since I like to obey proper ownership. Thank you very much.

This took me a minute to figure out. It's a subtle annoyance, but the sol include files are normally specified as -isystem in the makefile at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/2e2d2ab49d3058a0222bf35ebb7f76aec4a23991/sdk/sbf/c/sbf.mk#L40, whereas the INC_DIRS is specified as -I at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/2e2d2ab49d3058a0222bf35ebb7f76aec4a23991/sdk/sbf/c/sbf.mk#L42
I'm not an expert in this area, but it appears that by treating those include files as vendored, the compiler won't warn for them. I found some info about the difference at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Options-for-Directory-Search
So if you want to fix this, you can update the sbf.mk file in your local installation to treat INC_DIRS as -isystem. Or you can have your sbf.mk file point to your local C headers instead of the bundled ones. Up to you!
